# Calling the sendLine() method after the connectTCP method has been called on twisted

Tags: python, client-server, twisted

I made a simple server that uses the LineReceiver. I can manage to send and receive messages when I test with Telnet.

I want to take things a little bit further and use a small GUI to send and receive the messages.

The way I am picturing this is that I somehow will have some sort of connect function that will call the reactor.run() method, and also make an instance of the ClientFactory class. I am basing myself with this example I found:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.


from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor
import sys

class EchoClient(LineReceiver):
    end="Bye-bye!"
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("Hello, world!")
        self.sendLine("What a fine day it is.")
        self.sendLine(self.end)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "receive:", line
        if line==self.end:
            self.transport.loseConnection()

    def sendMessage(self, line):
        self.sendLine(line)

class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection failed:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection lost:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        reactor.stop()

def main():
    factory = EchoClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 1234, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Observe that when I call the main() function, the connectionMade will send those messages.

How can I run the reactor and the factory, and call the sendLine function?

Comment: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonAndTwisted have tried this

Comment: self.protocol = None  # twisted Protocol (Line 13)... Am I supposed to declare my own protocol here? On the client.

Answer (score 1):

Twisted calls are broken up into things that queue future actions and things that act immediately (or near to immediately) if the reactor is running.  You can combine those to schedule something to happen in the future. (see: [Scheduling tasks for the future](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/time.html))

So if you want to call sendLine in the future you could use `reactor.callLater(5, sendLine, arg_to_sendLine)`.  That would schedule the `sendLine` call to be run 5 seconds after the `callLater` call (... Assuming that your code is in the `reactor.run()` state)

You also said:

> The way I am picturing this is that I somehow will have some sort of connect function that will call the reactor.run() method

That statement worries me because Twisted is an all-encompassing framework (in most twisted programs `reactor.run()` and it's setup calls become the whole of `main`) not just something that you start when you want to do communications (it reacts poorly when you try and only use it halfway).

Comment: Using time-based events to handle non-time-based events is a half-broken approach to avoiding learning about non-time-based events.  The question isn't *super* clear but I think what the poster really wants is to be able to respond to the "the client connection has now been established" event.  Also, there's https://github.com/itamarst/crochet for using Twisted alongside naive blocking code.  I wouldn't go so far as to say Twisted "reacts poorly" in this situation - on the other hand, I'd try very, very hard not to have to use Twisted this way before resorting to crochet. :)